# Why the screen function is always wrong？

Tags: python, pygame

main.py

```
import sys

import pygame

from settings import Settings

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen.height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Rocket Flying")

    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

            screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)

            pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

settings.py

```
class Settings():

    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (87,250,255)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

> ```
> File "C:\Users\C4nEzra\Desktop\Program\Rocket_Flaying\main.py", line 24, in <module> run_game()
> File "C:\Users\C4nEzra\Desktop\Program\Rocket_Flaying\main.py", line 11, in run_game
>  (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen.height))
> AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'screen'
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you initially write `ai_settings.screen_width` for the first argument in the `set_mode(...)` function but the second argument has `ai_settings.screen.height`. Most likely you need to replace the second period for an underscore (`ai_settings.screen_height`).

Comment: There is a recommendation not to answer typo-question. Questions like these are off-topic and should not be answered but closed as they are not helpful to other contributors. The questions will be closed and finally deleted. If the question is deleted, your gained reputation points will be lost.v